# Select Count with Distinct and Union All

Tags: mysql

I have a query like :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `ID`) FROM db1.table UNION ALL SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `ID`) FROM db2.table
```

My real query is more complicate, i have LEFT JOIN and multiple condition etc...

This query return to me an array with 2 results : `Count 1` and `Count 2`

How can i only return one result ? `Count 1 + Count 2` ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `ID`) FROM db1.table) + 
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `ID`) FROM db2.table)
```

If you also want to return separate `db1`, `db2` counts, then use this query:

```
SELECT countDb1, countDb2, countDb1 + countDb2 AS total
FROM (
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `ID`) FROM db1.table) AS countDb1,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `ID`) FROM db2.table) AS countDb2) AS t
```